# Can a COTS FM Radio transmit?

Tags: rf, basic

This is probably a really silly question, but I still want to know...

Given a standard off-the-shelf FM radio alarm clock, what is to stop it from transmitting radio waves when physical motion causes the speaker to move?

The theory is that if FM waves can come in to the antenna, through any tuning circuit, and be spit out as audible noise on a speaker, why not the reverse when I move the speaker, say by flicking it softly a couple of times. In the perfect laboratory scenario, would I see **any** RF output from doing this? If so, would it be anything more than just RF noise?

Yes, I realize this is not a good setup. No, I'm not trying to implement anything. Thinking theoretically, I just wonder if it's a one-way street or not in a COTS FM clock radio.

Comment: Does your car make fuel when you push it?

Comment: interestingly (well to me anyway) your FM radio does transmit when you use it in the normal way as a receiver. The local oscillator produces a VHF signal. You can pick it up with another FM radio close by. It will usually be 10.7MHz away from the frequency that the receiver is tuned to.

Comment: @user1582568 Yes a superheterodyne receiver will transmit and most receivers these days are. Detecting the intermediate frequency is the trick used in radar-detector-detectors. The frequency however will not vary with RF nor LF signals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you shine a torch on an incandescent lamp will voltage come out - no it won't. If you heat up a resistor will DC voltage come out - no but you'll get more noise voltage (a few micro volts maybe).

The back stage of a receiver is an audio power amp and you might see a few microvolts of signal at its input when you shout loudly into the speaker but, the big killer is that an FM radio uses a demodulator to extract the audio from the carrier and, when you force a signal on to the output of the demodulator, a fully modulated FM signal **does not** appear at its inputs.

To produce an FM signal you need a modulator and no matter how hard you might shout into the speaker, a demodulator run backwards does not make a modulator.

Next is the problem of the intermediate frequency stages. Next is the mixer stage and finally a sensitive front-end amplifier.

No it just won't work at all.

Comment: What about AM radio?

Comment: @kmort - I think you are missing the point - go look up what a basic AM envelope detector does and see if somehow it can produce a carrier from nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

> In the perfect laboratory scenario, would I see any RF output from doing this?

If the receiver is a "Superheterodyne receiver" (as many COTS FM radios are) there is a local oscilator (LO) which operates at a similar frequency to the frequency the radio receives. Some of the output from the LO is likely to leak back to the antenna and be radiated. Under laboratory conditions this is likely to be detectable (and if the person monitoring has knowlage of the receivers design they can work out what frequency the receiver is tuned to). This applies regardless of whether the speaker is moving or not.

> If so, would it be anything more than just RF noise?

The LO output will not be noise as such, it will be a pretty stable single frequency source.

The movement of the speaker will obviously introduce electrical currents into the system. In principle this could modulate the power supply slightly which in turn could modulate the output of the local oscilator slightly.

I suspect that any modulation of the LO by movements in the speaker would be too small to measure even under laboratory conditions but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: What about AM radio?